# Field Index in WHERE clause in Excel SELECT statement

Tags: sql, excel

I'm forced to work with Excel files that have "field names" in first row with excessive formatting, such as multi-line text with first line in bold and second in smaller font, italic. I am using SqlBulkCopy to copy data and can map using source column indexes. The problem is I need to select everything where particular field is not NULL:

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select " + fileID.ToString() + 
" as [FileID], * from [Sheet1$] where [Body] IS NOT NULL", 
excelConnection);
```

I don't have [Body] column. Is there a way to reference, let's say, third column?

Comment: I still would like to see a solution to this. To work around the problem, I added temporary code changes to populate a DataSet with data from my sample Excel file and then peek at the column name of the DataTable. My statement became this: 
cmd = new OleDbCommand
                       ("Select " + fileID.ToString() + " as [FileID], * from [Sheet1$] where [Text                                 (No Character Limit)] IS NOT NULL",
                           excelConnection);

You don't see a lot of spaces between [Text and the rest of the name, but they're there.